# java RE class - lookahead (implementing password validator)

Tags: java, regex, apache

i'm trying to conjure a regex to validate that a given password contains:
1. an upper case character 
2. a lower case character 
3. a number
4. at least 8 characters long

i found the following regex to define such constraints:

```
RE r = new RE("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$");
```

unfortunately, i'm confined to a legacy system that uses java's org.apache.regexp.RE class.

without lookahead, i was able to define rules 1-3 as the following regex:

```
RE r = new RE("^(((.*([A-Z]+).*([0-9]+).*|.*([0-9]+).*([A-Z]+)).*)$)")
```

but i don't know how to add the length parameter to this string without using the "?=" meta-character.

trying to compile "(?=...)" fails with the following error:

```
org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.branch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.expr(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.branch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.expr(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RE.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.regexp.RE.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.idit.hscx.passwordTest.testPassword(passwordTest.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

my question: 
is "lookahead" exists in class RE?
if not, how do i implement the "AND" operator in RE class regex?

thanks!

Comment: if there is so much restriction, use simple check for existence of those characters

Comment: Just use two regexes. There's no reason to need just one

Comment: Two questions: Q1 what happens if you use a lookahead with a fixed number of characters like `^(?=.{0,8}[a-z])` or `^(?=.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?[a-z])` instead of the infinite `.*?`.  Q2 what happens if you use a lookbehind like `(?<=[a-z].{0,8})$` or `(?<=[a-z].?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?)$`. I ask because java doesn't really like the infinite lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

The second expression you listed only tests for 2 of the 4 conditions. It looks for just upper case and numbers.

I can think of a couple ways to do this.

First off there are six different combinations of uppercase, lowercase, and numbers.

- ULN
- UNL
- LUN
- LNU
- NLU
- NUL

## Plan A

Use two regex expressions. The first expression would validate there is at least one of each character type in your string. It's kinda long because it looks for each of the six combinations.

`^.*?(?:[A-Z]+.*?[a-z]+.*?[0-9]|[A-Z]+.*?[0-9]+.*?[a-z]|[a-z]+.*?[A-Z]+.*?[0-9]|[a-z]+.*?[0-9]+.*?[A-Z]|[0-9]+.*?[a-z]+.*?[A-Z]|[0-9]+.*?[A-Z]+.*?[a-z])`

The second test could be either a regex or a string length test. The regex would look like:

`^.{8,}`

## Plan B

Would be to construct a much more complex regex that would test all the different combinations of Uppercase, Lowercase and Numbers in each position. This regex would naturally be enormous.